# On focus, focus on another element jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

**Question:**

Why isn't the below code working?

**PROBLEM:**

I have a menu which consists of drop downs. (Two level navigation / firefox) When I tab through the website it will focus on the first level of the navigation. It won't go down into the individual items of that drop down.
When I cycle through with chrome it only cycles through the first two tabs of the menu.

**THE CODE I'M TRYING:**

```
$('#cssmenu ul li').focus(function() {
  $('#cssmenu li ul a').focus();
});
```

LINK OF MENU: http://www.casa.gov.au

Comment: You can use classes! So that, once pressed tab key it focusses the next one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the original question, one reason the code you had wasn't working is because the focus event triggers on the `<a>` tag in the `#cssmenu` line items, but your were attaching the focus listener to the `<li>` tags.

This might accomplish the original intent for the focus event, but may not solve the tab skipping issue:

```
$(function(){
  $('#cssmenu ul li a').focus(function() {
    var parentLi = $(this).parent();
    if(parentLi.find("ul").length > 0){
      parentLi.find("ul li:first a").focus();
    }
  });
});
```

I tested it out in this jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ryKZu/3/

Comment: Based on the jsfiddle it seems like it is skipping the first level navigation and immediately proceeding to the first item.

I added the code to the website and it seems to skip all tabs but the home tab.

Comment: I suspect this isn't a focus/js issue and has more to do with the way tabbing is handled by the browser with respect to the HTML of the menu. The js in my answer will shift focus to the first element of a dropdown when you tab to its parent menu item (it looked like that's what you were trying to do), but I think there is a larger issue influencing the tab behavior. I might suggest submitting a different question that refers more broadly to the tab skipping.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: Fixed the selectors

```
$('#cssmenu > ul > li > a').focus(function () {
    $(this).parent().find('ul li a').first().focus();
});
```

Try that. Read up on jQuery's selectors: http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/

Comment: I just tried that, and it still isn't working. It acted exactly as it did before.

Comment: @sephiith Please try the updated code. Your menu is pure css, correct?

Comment: That is correct. You can see the code at: www.casa.gov.au. No luck, still no change.